# VSCode Extension: How can you tell if an Intellisense suggestion has been clicked?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

While working on suggestions inside of my VSCode extension, I've been unable to tell if the user has clicked my suggestion.

For example down below, this works to show log, warn or error if the user types "console." however if the click "warn", for example, is there a way to fire a function or know that they clicked it?

```
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) { 
const provider2 = vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider(
    'plaintext',
    {
        provideCompletionItems(document: vscode.TextDocument, position: vscode.Position) {

            // get all text until the `position` and check if it reads `console.`
            // and if so then complete if `log`, `warn`, and `error`
            const linePrefix = document.lineAt(position).text.substr(0, position.character);
            if (!linePrefix.endsWith('console.')) {
                return undefined;
            }

            return [
                new vscode.CompletionItem('log', vscode.CompletionItemKind.Method),
                new vscode.CompletionItem('warn', vscode.CompletionItemKind.Method),
                new vscode.CompletionItem('error', vscode.CompletionItemKind.Method),
            ];
        }
    },
    '.' // triggered whenever a '.' is being typed
);

context.subscriptions.push(provider2);
```

Comment: check after the completion item list calculated if the editor content changed and it is one of the suggestions after the cursor

Comment: This might work: give the completion item a `command` - if it is triggered that item was selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say your completionItem i s called `item` in the function where you are actually constructing the completionItem.  You can add a `command` property to any or all items that will be fired upon selection of that item from the suggestion list.

```js
let newCommand = {};

// call command 'selectDigitInCompletion' defined in extension.js
// rename it to what you want
newCommand.command = "find-and-transform.selectDigitInCompletion";

// some descriptive title
newCommand.title = "Select the digit 'n' in completionItem";

// whatever arguments you put here will be available when the command is called, key is the completion text in my use
newCommand.arguments = [key, replaceRange];  

item.command = newCommand;
```

Then return your array of completionItems.  Register the `"find-and-transform.selectDigitInCompletion"` somewhere.  This command selects part of the completion key `n` that was just added and needs to be replaced by the user with some digit.

```js
let selectDigitInCompletion = vscode.commands.registerCommand('find-and-transform.selectDigitInCompletion', async (completionText, completionRange) => {

// do what you want when that completion item was selected, or check `completionText` to see which was selected.
// you can modify what is inserted here

  // args = [completionText, Range] from makeCompletionItem function
  // if completionText startsWith '\\U$n' or '${n'
  let keyLength;
  if (completionText?.startsWith("${n")) keyLength = 3;
  else if (completionText?.search(/^\\\\[UuLl]\$n/m) === 0) keyLength = 5;
  else if (completionText?.search(/^\$\{getTextLines:n/m) === 0) keyLength = 16;
  else return;

  if (completionRange?.start) {
    const digitStart = new vscode.Position(completionRange.start.line, completionRange.start.character + keyLength - 1);
    const digitEnd = new vscode.Position(completionRange.start.line, completionRange.start.character + keyLength);
    vscode.window.activeTextEditor.selection = new vscode.Selection(digitStart, digitEnd);
  }
});

context.subscriptions.push(selectDigitInCompletion);
```